# Simplecov coverage and Spree decorators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, simplecov

I'm trying to use simplecov to get some spec coverage of my customisations to a Spree powered store.

Classes are usually stored in `/app/models/spree/price_decorator.rb` and in the file we crack open the class with a `Spree::Price.class_eval` block to include our custom logic.

However files aren't showing up in SimpleCov, I'm unsure if it's a technical limitation or is there a chance to have them in the final output.

SimpleCov is currently configured in a very simple way:

```
require 'simplecov'

SimpleCov.start 'rails' do
  add_group 'Workers', 'app/workers'
end
```

I tried to `add_group` with `app/models/spree` but it doesn't work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have tests for `price_decorator.rb`?

Comment: yes, of course, full model spec

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work for you if you put it into your application.rb config file (obviously it goes inside your class Application < Rails::Application)

I use simplecov for my Spree application and my decorators show up fine. I think maybe it's just a matter of your decotorators not being loaded by the app's bootup.

```html
 config.to_prepare do
      # Load application's model / class decorators
      Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../app/**/*_decorator*.rb")) do |c|
        Rails.configuration.cache_classes ? require(c) : load(c)
 end
```

Comment: yeah I have that snipped of code (spree default), but it's very weird I don't get decorators to show up, not sure where else to look. Thanks.